# Flutter: google founding choice

Tags: flutter, gdpr

Я использую [admob_consent](https://pub.dev/packages/admob_consent), делаю все по инструкций

использую андроид

Ожидаю открытия диалога, но после вызова, этого не происходит

```
_admobConsent.show (forceShow: true);
```

консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы решить эту проблему, необходимо выбрать "персонализированную рекламу" для пользователей из ЕЭЗ и Великобритании в admob.

https://apps.admob.com/v2/pubcontrols/eu-user-consent